# Overload resolution between const lvalue reference and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference, overload-resolution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void fnc (const std::string&)
{
    std::cout<<1;
}

void fnc (std::string&&)
{
    std::cout<<2;
}

int main()
{
    fnc ("abc");
}
```

All the compilers choose `std::string&&` version of `fnc`, and it is logical, because the temporary `std::string` is created for a reference binding, but I can't find, where is it described in C++ 14 Standard.
I found one paragraph in there (3.2):

> — Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> [...]
>
> — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an
>   implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared
>   without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an **rvalue**
>   and S2 binds an lvalue reference

But it isn't that case, because S1 binds an rvalue reference to an **lvalue** ("abc", lvalue of const char[4]).
Where can I find description, by which the second overload is selected?

P.S. I pointed to C++14 Standard instead of C++11, because I know, that there was some defect reports in C++11, linked with rvalue reference binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First the compiler performs an implicit array-to-pointer conversion for `"abc"`, so the type of `"abc"` becomes `const char*`. Second (and you probably missed that), `const char*` is converted to a **rvalue** `std::string` via the `const char*` [non-explicit constructor of `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (# 5 in the link). The constructed `std::string` rvalue  is a perfect match for the second overload, so the second overload is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

> But it isn't that case, because S1 binds an rvalue reference to an lvalue ("abc", lvalue of const char[4]).

Note that `"abc"` is a `const char[4]`, not a `std::string`. But both `fnc()` take `std::string` as parameter, and references can't be bound to objects with different type directly. Therefore firstly `"abc"` needs to be implicitly converted to `std::string`, which is a temporary, i.e. **an rvalue**. Then as the stardard says, the rvalue reference overload will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

`"abc"` cannot be passed directly into either overload of `fnc()`. For both of them it must be converted to an (rvalue) `std::string`. But then the cited rule from the standard unequivocally selects `fnc(std::string&&)` over `fnc(const std::string&)`.