# How does std::map resolve insert() overload between const lvalue reference and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, templates, std, stdmap, rvalue-reference

I am writing a template library that is supposed to mirror std::map's interface. I stumbled across a question when implementing the following insert() overloads.

```cpp
iterator insert( const value_type& value );
template< class P > iterator insert( P&& value );
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) writes about the second overload: The overload is equivalent to `emplace(std::forward<P>(value))` and only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_constructible<value_type, P&&>::value == true`.

Given this, I am wondering for which possible arguments `std::is_constructible` will ever be false? I have experimented a bit with possible types but everything I have tried so far fulfils the requirement.

```cpp
std::map<std::string,int> map;
std::cout
<< ((std::is_constructible<std::map<std::string,int>::value_type, const std::pair<const std::string,int>&&>::value)? "yes" : "no")
<< ((std::is_constructible<std::map<std::string,int>::value_type, const std::pair<std::string,int>&&>::value)? "yes" : "no")
<< ((std::is_constructible<std::map<std::string,int>::value_type, std::pair<const std::string,int>&&>::value)? "yes" : "no")
<< ((std::is_constructible<std::map<std::string,int>::value_type, std::pair<std::string,int>&&>::value)? "yes" : "no")
<< std::endl;
```

Output:

```
yesyesyesyes
```

**In other words, how can I specifically call the first overload over the second?**

Possibly related questions:

- [Preventing non-const lvalues from resolving to rvalue reference instead of const lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748104/preventing-non-const-lvalues-from-resolving-to-rvalue-reference-instead-of-const?rq=1)
- [Overload resolution between const lvalue reference and rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564690/overload-resolution-between-const-lvalue-reference-and-rvalue-reference)

Comment: The `is_constructible` sorts out totally wrong parameters, like `complex<double>`. Otherwise `P&&` would match absolutely everything! There is another overload rule that favors non-templates over templates, which can give the first version a chance when it matches exactly.

Comment: I understand now. I was confused because the wording on cppreference made it sound like the second overload is more restricted that the first, when it's the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing overload resolution on const lvalue ref vs rvalue ref, you are doing overload resolution on const lvalue ref to concrete type vs rvalue ref to template parameter.

This means the first overload is a better match whenever you are passing cvref `value_type`, and the second is a better match otherwise. (Neither match when you pass something unrelated)

Comment: Just tested it with my own implementation and that's exactly right, I can reproduce this behaviour. Many thanks!